# Mongo Aggregation/Projection from a subdocument

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Can't get my head around the specific syntax for querying this mongo document.
I want to get (project?) only the "entries" where u="123".
I tried something like that:

```
db["conv_msgs_822"].aggregate({$match: {"_id": "1234", "entries.$.u" : "123"}})
```

Which fails. Is this even possible?

```
{
  "_id" : "1234",
  "entries" : {
    "1" : {
      "body" : "aesf asdf asdf asdf asdf",
      "u" : "123"
    },
    "2" : {
      "body" : "1234",
      "u" : ""
    },
    "3" : {
      "body" : "some other body ",
      "u" : "14"
    },
    "4" : {
      "body" : "another body",
      "u" : "123"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it would be useful if you could show us the structure of the document you have in your collection.

Comment: You want to use $unwind with a second match and then a $group with a $push, do a Google Search (P.S you wanna change your document structure too)

Comment: @Hrishi what do you mean ? the document shown above is the actual document I'm querying.

Comment: @Sammaye What do you mean by "You wanna change you document structure too" ? 95% of the the time, my query would be to simply get the document as a whole. In few cases, I'd be required to do the above iteration, I can always filter that in the code, however, I'm trying to see if there is a simple way to do so on the mongo side. Do you thing in such scenario splitting this to multiple documents is worth while ?

Comment: You have an object of nested objects, that won't unwind. Unless that's a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best potential for this so far for me is:

```
db.eval( function(doc, u_val) {
            var msgs = doc["entries"];
            var cleaned_entries = {};
              for (var k in entries){
                if (msgs[k].u == u_val){
                  cleaned_entries[k] = entries[k];
                  }
              };
            doc["entries"] = cleaned_entries

            return doc
         },
         db["conv_msgs_822"].findOne({"_id": "1234"}), 123 );
```

Answer (score 3):

This really isn't possible with your current document structure. You really need those subdocuments to be in an array to do something like this.

Let's assume you restructure the docs to match this (you can even add back the indexes as a field if needed in the subdocument):

```
{
  "_id" : "1234",
  "entries" : [
    {
      "body" : "aesf asdf asdf asdf asdf",
      "u" : "123"
    },
    {
      "body" : "1234",
      "u" : ""
    },
    {
      "body" : "some other body ",
      "u" : "14"
    },
    {
      "body" : "another body",
      "u" : "123"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you could use a basic query with a `$` operator as a projection to match only the first item.

```
> db.conv_msgs_822.find({"_id": "1234", "entries.u": "123"}, {"entries.$": 1})
```

Which would yield:

```
{ "_id" : "1234", "entries" : [ { "body" : "aesf asdf asdf asdf asdf", "u" : "123" } ] }
```

To match all the items you will need to aggregate and `$unwind` them `$match` the subelements and `$group` them back.

```
db.conv_msgs_822.aggregate(
  {$match: {"_id": "1234", "entries.u": "123"}},
  {$unwind: "$entries"},
  {$match: {"entries.u": "123"}},
  {$group: {_id: "$_id", entries: {$push: "$entries"}}}
)
```

resulting in:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "1234",
            "entries" : [
                {
                    "body" : "aesf asdf asdf asdf asdf",
                    "u" : "123"
                },
                {
                    "body" : "another body",
                    "u" : "123"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Appreciate the input very much, however, the document structure of array will not allow updating the specific entries, something that happens on some occasions. I couldn't get the aggregation approach to work, I'll keep on trying on that.